# Angular - resource object is sometimes undefined?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have a simple app using Angular which feeds off of Tastypie REST resources.

I have a resource defined using a factory:

```
app.factory("Task", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/v1/task/:id/", {scheduling: '@scheduling', meta_only: '@meta_only'});
  });
```

and a simple controller with several functions:

```
app.controller("TasksController", function($scope, Task){

   Task.get(function(data){ 
       $scope.tasks = data.objects;
   });

   $scope.markAsDone = function(task){
       task.is_done = true;
       task.$save();
   }
}
```

View has a simple ng-repeat of tasks and a checkbox which calls markAsDone(task) on ng-change. There are several other similar simple functions.

Now from time to time I get an error saying "undefined is not a function" when I call task.$save(). I can't figure out when and why I do and don't get this error as it sometimes works as expected. I did manage to log "task" in the function in both cases and sure thing, when the error happens, it's an Object, and when it doesn't, it has all these properties and functions defined that Angular uses.

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps you ars dealing with asynchronous loading issues, basically when $resource is not finished you already call the ouput. The way to deal with it is using callbacks. Check angular $q module or search for Asynchronous AngularJS on Stackoverflow

Comment: I don't think that's it. I'm calling $save() when my object is already prepared.

Comment: Understood, I am not entirely familiar with it. Out of curiosity, could you explain how you do that? I am not seeing it directly from the code.

Comment: I'm working with a list of tasks that are loaded using Task.get() function. Once the tasks are loaded, they're stored in the scope - that's what the first part in the controller does.

The second part defines a function which is called when a user clicks on a checkbox in the view. It's bound to a task (a task from a list loaded in the first part of the code).

Comment: Got it. Only part I don't understand is where you define what happens when the tasks are loaded, like I don't see .then or .success callbacks (am still looking into this subject). Thats why I thought you were dealing with asynchronously loading.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry. The unnamed function in Task.get(function(){}); is the success callback. In other words, when get successfully finishes, the function inside the brackets is executed.

Comment: This probably is not true for your case, but I've broken DI when Function.prototype was used as controller, which was pretty stupid in the end. After Angular adds $inject to it, all consecutive annotate calls don't add anything because $inject is already in the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

Add a check as

```js
$scope.markAsDone = function(task){
   if(typeof task !== undefined){
      task.is_done = true;
      task.$save();
   }
}
```